# How to reconstruct regex matched part

Tags: regex, perl

I have simplify some latex math formula within text, for example

```
This is ${\text{BaFe}}_{2}{\text{As}}_{2}$ crystal
```

I want to transform this into

```
This is BaFe2As2 crystal
```

That is to concatenate only content within inner most bracket.

I figure out that I can use regex pattern

```
\{[^\{\}]*\}
```

to match those inner most bracket. But the problem is how to concatenate them together?

I don't know if this could be done in notepad++ regex replacement. If notepad++ is not capable, I can also accept perl one-liner solution.

Comment: I assume that you have more than one of these in the document. Are they all inline equations (between single `$`s), like the one shown, or are there also displayed ones?

Comment: @zdim They are all inlines

Comment: Perhaps if you can use Sublime you might try `(?:\$(?=[^$]+\$)|\G(?!\A)){(?>{([^{}]+)}|[^{}]+|(?R))*}_?\$?` and replace with the first capturing group `$1` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/FXPiu0/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may clearly be multiple such equations (the markup between two `$`s) in the document. So while you need to assemble text between all `{}`, this also need be constrained within a `$` pair. Then all such equations need be processed.

Matching that in a single pattern results in a complex regex. Instead, we can first extract everything within a pair of `$`s and then gather text within `{}`s from that, simplifying the regex a lot.  This makes two passes over each equation but a Latex document is small for computational purposes and the loss of efficiency can't be noticed.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my $text = q(This is ${\text{BaFe}}_{2}{\text{As}}_{2}$ crystal,)
         . q( and ${\text{Some}}{\mathbf{More}}$ text);

my @results;

while ($text =~ /\$(.*?)\$/g) { 
    my $eq = $1; 
    push @results, join('', $eq =~ /\{([^{}]+)\}/g);
} 

say for @results;
```

This prints lines `BaFe2As2` and `SomeMore`.

The regex in the `while` condition captures all chars between two `$`s. After the body of the loop executes and the condition is checked again, the regex continues searching the string from the position of the previous match. This is due to the "global" [modifier `/g`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Using-regular-expressions-in-Perl) in scalar [context](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Context), imposed on regex since it is in the loop condition. Once there are no more matches the loop terminates.

In the body we match between `{}`, and again due to `/g` this is done for all `{}`s in the equation. Here, however, the regex is in the list context (as it is assigned to an array) and then `/g` makes it return all matches. They are joined into a string, which is added to the array.

In order to replace the processed equation, use this in a substitution instead

```
$text =~ s{ \$(.*?)\$ }{ join('', $1 =~ /\{([^{}]+)\}/g) }egx;
```

where the modifier `e` makes it so that the replacement part is evaluated as Perl code, and the result of that used to replace the matched part. Then in it we can run our regex to match content of all `{}` and join it into the string, as explained above. I use `s{}{}` delimiters, and `x` modifier so to be able to space things in the matching part as well.

Since the whole substitution has the `g` modifier the regex keeps going through `$text`, as long as there are equations to match, replacing them with what's evaluated in the replacement part.

I use a hard-coded string (extended) from the question, for an easy demo. In reality you'd read a file into a scalar variable ("slurp" it) and process that.

This relies on the question's premise that text of interest in an equation is cleanly between `{}`.

---

Missed the part that a one-liner is sought

```
perl -0777 -wnE'say join("", $1=~/\{([^{}]+)\}/g) while /\$(.*?)\$/g' file.tex
```

With `-0777` the file is read whole ("slurped"), and as `-n` provides a loop over input lines it is in the `$_` variable; the regex in the `while` condition works by default on `$_`.  In each interation of `while` the contents of the captured equation, in `$1`, is directly matched for `{}`s.

Then to replace each equation and print out the whole processed file

```
perl -0777 -wne's{\$(.*?)\$}{join "", $1=~/\{([^{}]+)\}/g}eg; print' file.tex
```

where I've removed extra spaces and (unnecessary) parens on `join`.

Comment: @user15964 I used your string, slightly extended, as an example. Let me know if it would be useful to show how to read a file into `$text` instead. (Which is what you would actually do.)

Comment: @user15964  I had missed that you wanted specifically a _one-liner_.  Added.

Comment: @user15964 Aparently I also missed that you want to have those equations _replaced_ (even as you clearly state that!).  Added that, to both the script version and the one-liner. Sorry about back and forths.

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution and thorough explanation ! Really learned a lot from your answer as a perl beginner : )

Comment: @user15964 Really glad to hear that :)  Let me know if something is missing or unclear, I'll add/edit.

Answer (score 1):

Use this regex in Notepad++. I have tried to match everything which is NOT present between the innermost curly brackets and then replaced the match with a blank string.

```
[^{}]*\{|\}[^{}]*
```

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/JizAv4/2/)**

**Explanation:**

- `[^{}]*\{` - matches 0+ occurrences of any character that is neither `{` nor `}` followed by `{`
- `|` - OR
- `\}[^{}]*` - matches `}` followed by 0+ occurrences of any character that is neither `{` nor `}`

Before Replacement:

[image]

After Replacement:

[image]

**UPDATE:**

Try this updated regex:

```
\$?(?=[^$]*\$[^$]*$)(?:[^{}]*{|}[^{}]*)(?=[^$]*\$[^$]*$)\$?
```

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/JizAv4/5)**

Comment: Quite great! upvoted. However, I found your method is opposite to my intention. In reality, I have to deal with latex fomula within text. So for example, change "This is ${\text{BaFe}}_{2}{\text{As}}_{2}$ crystal" into "This is BaFe2As2 crystal". This is my fault, I'll update my post.

Comment: @user15964 I have added an update that should do the job.

Comment: Thank you so much! Have you tried the updated version in notepad++, it seems not compatible in notepad++ as I test

Comment: @user15964 After escaping the curly brackets, it is working in Notepad++ too - `\$?(?=[^$]*\$[^$]*$)(?:[^{}]*\{|\}[^{}]*)(?=[^$]*\$[^$]*$)\$?`